# Facebook login button doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm trying to add facebook login button to my web app.

The button is just doesn't show up.

I'm new to this stuff, so I already have wasted 3 day to this issue. Your help is needed.

Here is the code (pretty standard, from FB developers, with my chenges where they are required):

```
 <script>
       function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {

      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '45349573495739', //My app ID is entered here
    cookie     : true,  
    channelUrl : 'localhost:8080/DBConnector/main.jsp', //My app page. The same is in FB app properties.                   
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';


      });
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/DBConnector/main.jsp');
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    }); 
  }
</script>



<fb:login-button size="xlarge" scope="public_profile,email" show_faces="false" onlogin="function() {
    checkLoginState();
    window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/DBConnector/main.jsp');}">
</fb:login-button>
```

### EDIT:

The button appeared once, I tried to login, but I'm not sure if the login process went OK. 
Then the button disappeared again. I thought it doesn't show because I'm already logged in, so I added `show_faces="false"` to login button code, but still nothing.

Comment: Start by removing everything you don't need to display the login button. And then add more and more stuff until you button disappear

Comment: You mean, remove stuff from 'fb:login-button' tag?

Comment: Just a different thought. Could it be that you are already logged in? If you saw it once I'm pretty sure that you don't see it because you already logged in.

Comment: Shouldn't the login button turn into logout then?